# Using DPDK and a Mellanox Connect-x 5 card, how can I direct incoming traffic to different queues based on ip/port?

Tags: c++, dpdk

I am using the following:

-Ubuntu 22.04.1

-DPDK 22.11

-Mellanox Connect-X 5 100gbe

I have two streams of data coming in to a single 100gbe port. Each stream has a unique ip/port number. I need to sort this data without having to look at each header.

On the DPDK side I have one core per queue, with the 100gbe port having two queues. How can I get ip traffic to go to a certain queue based on ip/port? Is that possible? I thought possibly using RSS or some sort of offloads that this could be done.

Answer (score 0):

With DPDK rte_flow, of course you can direct flows to specific queues.

https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/rte_flow.html

See Queue action, RSS action. Also isolate mode could help you leave other flow to the kernel.

But if you already knew DPDK, it would not bother you if you have checked the doc first.

Comment: I did look at this example and do not think it will work. Once the flow is established all traffic is directed to the queue. The data I am receiving could be two distinct ip/ports and this would result in my data getting mixed. I am looking for a way to split the data without having to look at each header. I thought this could be done with RSS or some sort of offloads but I am not sure.

Comment: Just specify different queue id for these two flow rules.